# Splitting node content in JavaScript DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a scenario where I need to split a node up to a given ancestor, e.g.

```
<strong>hi there, how <em>are <span>you</span> doing</em> today?</strong>
```

needs to be split into:

```
<strong>hi there, how <em>are <span>y</span></em></strong>
```

and

```
<strong><em><span>ou</span> doing</em> today?</strong>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: based on what criteria?  Is this only for this situation or are there other similar places where you would need to do this?

Comment: Basically, I want to be able to take an offset (1, in this case) from a text node (`you`) and split it up to a given ancestor node (`<strong>`).

Comment: interesting... but at what point does it stop? in theory you could do this all the way up to the window object.  will it always be 2 parent levels deep?

Comment: I need it to stop at an ancestor node I specify (in this case, `<strong>`), so something like `splitNode(textNode, offset, ancestorNode)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution that will work for modern browsers using `Range`. Something similar could be done for IE < 9 using `TextRange`, but I use Linux so I don't have easy access to those browsers. I wasn't sure what you wanted the function to do, return the nodes or just do a replace inline. I just took a guess and did the replace inline.

```
function splitNode(node, offset, limit) {
  var parent = limit.parentNode;
  var parentOffset = getNodeIndex(parent, limit);

  var doc = node.ownerDocument;  
  var leftRange = doc.createRange();
  leftRange.setStart(parent, parentOffset);
  leftRange.setEnd(node, offset);
  var left = leftRange.extractContents();
  parent.insertBefore(left, limit);
}

function getNodeIndex(parent, node) {
  var index = parent.childNodes.length;
  while (index--) {
    if (node === parent.childNodes[index]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Demo: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/efegiz/2/edit)

It expects a `TextNode` for `node`, although it will work with an `Element`; the offset will just function differently based on the behavior of [Range.setStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.setStart)

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote it a little to use Rangy and jQuery for cross-browser compatibility and it works like a charm.

Comment: @rfw: FYI, Rangy has a built-in implementation of `getNodeIndex()` you can use: `rangy.dom.getNodeIndex()`. It just takes one parameter (`node`).

Answer (score 1):

See the method [`Text.splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text.splitText).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you, but this is what I came up with...

Pass the function an element and a node tag name string you wish to move up to.

```
<strong>hi there, how <em>are <span id="span">you</span> doing</em> today?</strong>

<script type="text/javascript">


  function findParentNode(element,tagName){
    tagName = tagName.toUpperCase();
    var parentNode = element.parentNode;
    if (parentNode.tagName == tagName){
    //Erase data up to and including the node name we passed
    console.log('Removing node: '+parentNode.tagName+'  DATA: '+parentNode.firstChild.data);
    parentNode.firstChild.data = '';
    return parentNode;
}
    else{
    console.log('Removing node: '+parentNode.tagName+'  DATA: '+parentNode.firstChild.data);
    //Erase the first child's data (the first text node and leave the other nodes intact)
    parentNode.firstChild.data = '';
    //Move up chain of parents to find the tag we want. Return the results so we can do things with it after
    return findParentNode(parentNode, tagName)
}
  }
var ourNode = document.getElementById("span");

alert(findParentNode(ourNode,'strong').innerHTML);


</script>
```