# Splitting node content in JavaScript DOM -

Tags: javascript, html

[This existing answer is an excellent piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237865/splitting-node-content-in-javascript-dom/7238184#7238184) that very nearly does what I want.  Like the OP in that questions I want HTML tags to be split, but based on a  tag rather than an offset, and bounded by an item that should not be split.

That is, I want to turn this:

```
<p>
  <strong>hi there, how <em>are <span>y<!--break-->ou</span> doing</em> today?</strong>
</p>
```

into this:

```
<p>
  <strong>hi there, how <em>are <span>y</span></em></strong>
  <!--break-->
  <strong><em><span>ou</span> doing</em> today?</strong>
</p>
```

I'm still getting my head around javascript so while I had a play with the jsbin provided by @Hemlock I couldn't get it to do what I intended.

The given answer was:

```
function splitNode(node, offset, limit) {
  var parent = limit.parentNode;
  var parentOffset = getNodeIndex(parent, limit);

  var doc = node.ownerDocument;  
  var leftRange = doc.createRange();
  leftRange.setStart(parent, parentOffset);
  leftRange.setEnd(node, offset);
  var left = leftRange.extractContents();
  parent.insertBefore(left, limit);
}

function getNodeIndex(parent, node) {
  var index = parent.childNodes.length;
  while (index--) {
    if (node === parent.childNodes[index]) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No ranges required, you just need to duplicate all the cut elements and move their children around:

```
function splitOn(bound, cutElement) {
    // will divide the DOM tree rooted at bound to the left and right of cutElement
    // cutElement must be a descendant of bound
    for (var parent = cutElement.parentNode; bound != parent; parent = grandparent) {
        var right = parent.cloneNode(false);
        while (cutElement.nextSibling)
            right.appendChild(cutElement.nextSibling);
        var grandparent = parent.parentNode;
        grandparent.insertBefore(right, parent.nextSibling);
        grandparent.insertBefore(cutElement, right);
    }
}
```

([jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s53jfp0x/))

Comment: Thank you  Very useful

Answer (score 1):

You could build your own split function by thinking how to split the content into an array and later concatinate the string together.

the problem with this answer is that it does not start/nor finish any split tag, like in your situation, is the SPAN element.

```
<script>
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('strong');
    var array = element.split("<!--break-->"); 

    var string = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        string += '<strong>' + sarray[i] + "</strong>';
    }

    content.innerHTML = string;
</script>

<div id="content">
    <strong>hi there, how <em>are <span>y<!--break-->ou</span> doing</em> today?</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Przemek, you get +1 for a good attempt.  The accepted answer is more flexible and suited to my needs though.